# Multivariate regression model that has two highly correlated variables, but performs "better"?

Tags: correlation, multiple-regression, p-value, multicollinearity

I have two variables (years_in_city and in_city_since) that have an r-squared of .97 between each other. years_in_city is calculated by taking the current year and subtracting in_city_since from it, so I understand why they are highly correlated and not independent of each other.

I am confused about why my model performs "better" when both are added? There are higher r-squared and adjusted r-squared values, and the p-values are low enough for all variables for the variables to be considered significant.

Is this a case where it would be OK to leave both the years variables in the model?

Here is a summary of when I remove one of the highly correlated variables:

```
Dep. Variable:  attendance  R-squared:  0.491           
Model:  OLS Adj. R-squared: 0.487           
Method: Least Squares   F-statistic:    140         
Date:   Wed, 15 Apr 2020    Prob (F-statistic): 4.68E-124           
Time:   19:15:02    Log-Likelihood: -12788          
No. Observations:   878 AIC:    2.56E+04            
Df Residuals:   871 BIC:    2.56E+04            
Df Model:   6                   
Covariance Type:    nonrobust                   

                   coef      std err       t      P>|t|    [0.025     0.975]
const          -2.75E+06    9.98E+05    -2.755  0.006   -4.71E+06   -7.91E+05

rollingwins     3.30E+04    2111.809    15.617    0       2.88E+04     3.71E+04

payroll           0.0045       0          9.88    0         0.004       0.005

parkscore          7.01E+05 7.30E+04       9.593 0        5.57E+05      8.44E+05

in_city_since      977.3641  503.549       1.941  0.053    -10.947      1965.676

abstemp          -2.25E+04    5237.591    -4.292    0     -3.28E+04    -1.22E+04

milestonextpark 247.0777    101.974        2.423    0.016   46.935       447.22

Omnibus:    72.783  Durbin-Watson:  0.723           
Prob(Omnibus):  0   Jarque-Bera (JB):   124.609         
Skew:   0.574   Prob(JB):   8.74E-28            
Kurtosis:   4.446   Cond. No.   4.96E+09
```

[image: years_in_city variable removed]

[image: This image is the summary when the two highly correlated (r-squared of .97) are both in the model.]

[image: descriptive stats for variables]

Comment: With just one response, this isn't best described as multivariate regression, a term better reserved for predicting two or more responses together.

Comment: Don't just look at R-square and P-values. Your results are highly fragile. With one of those two in the model its coefficient is positive. With both in, their coefficients flip to negative. Saying what you should be doing instead is harder, but I suspect problems here with skewness and outliers. You are fitting a plain regression model to a response that is presumably all positive and it's likely that you need to consider transformations and/or a generalized linear model. Attendance goes down with temperature, supposedly, given other variables: is this about skiing events?

Comment: Your dataset is too big, possibly, to post here, but summary statistics for the variables would help, e.g. mean, SD, min, median and quartiles, max for all.

Comment: abstemp is how close a city's temperature is to 70 degrees (absolute value of difference from 70). This is data on annual baseball attendance.

Comment: I added an image of descriptive stats

Comment: Thanks for the details. The temperature effect is interesting. I would use temperature $-$ 70 F and its square and not assume a symmetric effect. abstemp is not very clearly named. On this information payroll and attendance might well be better analysed on logarithmic scale.

Comment: Without knowing *anything* about the response, I'd still have a feeling that a logarithm should appear somewhere. Furthermore, you could try to use "current_year" and "years_in_city" as covariables instead of the two highly correlated ones.